# Posting form data and file via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

The text is posting fine but not the file.
I know that the php in mail-request.php is working because I tested it using an html form.
Here's what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn-quote').click(function() {
    alert("WORKING");
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "mail-request.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#load').html('<img src="load2.gif" width="50">');
        $("#err").fadeOut();
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //alert("AJAX: "+data);
        var f_data = data;
        $('#status').text(f_data);
      },
      error: function(errorThrown) {
        $('#status').text("DIDN'T WORK!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Here's the form:

```
<form id ="request-form" name="request-form" action="mail-request.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" >
      <!--</div>--> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form">
    <div class="md-form">
      <label for="fname" class="request-label">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="center-on-small-only"> <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-quote" onClick="validateRequestForm()">Submit Request</a> </div>
  <div class="status" id="status"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post the form. You are not adding any file to the form data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the form to the constructor of the FormData object, you are passing a DIV as you are in the div click handler.
Also just to make sure an event variable is available add it as a parameter to the event handler function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn-quote').click(function(event) {
    alert("WORKING");
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "mail-request.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: new FormData($('#request-form')[0]),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#load').html('<img src="load2.gif" width="50">');
        $("#err").fadeOut();
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //alert("AJAX: "+data);
        var f_data = data;
        $('#status').text(f_data);
      },
      error: function(errorThrown) {
        $('#status').text("DIDN'T WORK!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: 1000 Thank Yous! I was using serializeArray() to put the data into a variable and using data : myDataVar. That's where I was going wrong.There is one slight error in your script above. It should be data: new FormData($('#request-form')[0]). It's just missing the #.